# how to access superclass properties from child class when two properties overlap?

Tags: php, oop

I declare $age variable in both parent and child class. All combined classes inherit the superclass. When I declare 2 duplicate properties in parent class and child class. Then the $this keyword will point to the subclass. So how can I point to the $age property of the parent class?

Comment: I hope this case will teach you to never do this. What's the point of two properties with same name?

Comment: One of the major points of OOP is this. It is a feature. Parent classes define things, child classes use them, or if allowed by the parent, override them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.